# Getting an VBScript error

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

The following VBScript code giving me an error at the line"

```
    .Range(.Cells(lRow, lCol), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

***CORRECT***

```
    .Range(.Cells(lRow, lCol), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3)).Delete(-4159)
```

Error is: "Expected End of statement".

***CODE***

```
  Sub DataShiftFromRightToLeft(Ob6)

   Dim lCol,COL_FIRST,startCol
   Dim NUM_TASKS:NUM_TASKS=36

COL_FIRST = objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Parent Business Process ID", ob6.Rows(1), 0)
COL_FIRST=COL_FIRST+1

'Set wst = Ob6.ActiveSheet

With ob6.ActiveSheet

    For lRow = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        lTask = 1
        Do While lTask <= NUM_TASKS
            lCol = COL_FIRST + (lTask - 1) * 4
            If Len(.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value) = 0 And _
               Len(.Cells(lRow, lCol + 1).Value) = 0 And _
               Len(.Cells(lRow, lCol + 2).Value) = 0 And _
               Len(.Cells(lRow, lCol + 3).Value) = 0 Then
                ' make sure there is something to the right to shift over
                If .Cells(lRow, lCol).End(xlToRight).Column < .Columns.Count Then
                    ' delete the empty cells and shift everything left``
                    .Range(.Cells(lRow, lCol), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 3)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                Else
                    ' force the loop to the next row
                    lTask = NUM_TASKS + 1
                End If
            Else
                lTask = lTask + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next lRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: @TukalRakshit - please do some research (hint: calling Subs and Functions with parameters in VBScript and parentheses) to make your call to .Delete completely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Shift:=xlToLeft` is trying to use named parameters. This is not possible in VBScript. You have to define xlToLeft (Const) and to make sure that you pass `xlToLeft` at the correct position (use the VBA Docs to check the number and order of the arguments to .Delete).

**P.S.**

If you google for "vbscript delete xltoleft", [the first hit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/ITCG/thread/1ec5de28-4c87-4768-aa2d-52180d3cb091) will help you.

Comment: that,I will do,but how to format the line where it is getting the error,into vbscript? please help me

Comment: value of xlToLeft is -4159,i just got it. and now how to change the line,pls tell me?